# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! How to handle possible null objects?

Tags: java, comparator, contract

```
private Comparator<Entity> spriteSorter = new Comparator<Entity>() {
    public int compare(Entity e0, Entity e1) {
        if (e0 == null || e1 == null) return -1; //was 0
        if (e1.getY() < e0.getY()) return +1;
        if (e1.getY() > e0.getY()) return -1;
        return -1; //was 0
    }
};
```

I have read many articles about this one, but I still don't know how to solve this little problem:

This is the core that works:

```
if (e1.getY() < e0.getY()) return +1;
if (e1.getY() > e0.getY()) return -1;
```

But sometimes (I have to deal with many houndred entities which are being added and removed from a concurrent array list very often in a second) one of the entities is null. Therefore I have to check this inside this comparator.
But then I violate this general contract, once one of the two objects is null.

Any idea how I can solve this? Please help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparator, if called with `c.compare(null, null)`, will compare `null < null`, even though they are equal. Further, it breaks the rule for inverses, which is that `sgn(compare(a, b)) == -sgn(compare(b, a))`, that is, comparing two things backwards returns the opposite of comparing them forwards. You can fix all this simply by treating `null` as "negative infinity," that is enforcing that `null < a` for all nonnull `a` and `null == null`.

```
public int compare(Entity l, Entity r) {
    if (Objects.equals(l, r)) return 0; // Handles normal and null equality
    else if(l == null) return -1; // Enforce null < a ∀ nonnull a
    else if(r == null) return +1; // Enforce a > null ∀ nonnull a
    else return Integer.compare(l.getY(), r.getY()); // Base comparison
}
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you for this awesome explaination! It works!
One last question, For my specific case, I need the last line, that you wrote, without the minus before the Integer.compare.
Can I just change this, without breaking the rest of the contract?

Comment: Oh, I misread your question. Yes, go ahead, and I'll edit it out.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much and take care :)

Comment: Sorry, I got one more question! For Objects.equals, do I have to implement my own equals method inside the Entity class?

Comment: The default `Object::equals` that `Entity` inherits will do reference comparison (`l == r`). It will suffice for this purpose.